# The formula for the magnitude of cross product, $\| u\times v \| = \| u \| \|v \| \sin \theta $

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Can someone show me a proof of the magnitude (length) of the cross product: $$\|u \times v \| = \| u \| \|v \| \sin \theta $$

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the definition of cross product you use. The only definition for which the absolute value is not immediate is
$$
(x,y,z)\times(u,v,w)=(yw-zv,zu-xw,xv-yu)\tag{1}
$$
Note that the dot product is
$$
(x,y,z)\cdot(u,v,w)=xu+yv+zw\tag{2}
$$
A rotation is represented by a matrix $R$ so that $R^TR=I$. The dot product is invariant under rotations:
$$
\begin{align}
(Ra)\cdot(Rb)
&=(Ra)^T(Rb)\\
&=a^TR^TRb\\
&=a^Tb\\
&=a\cdot b\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since lengths are computed using dot products, lengths are preserved by rotations, also. Thus, the side lengths of the triangle formed by $a$, $b$, and $b-a$ are preserved, and likewise, $\theta$, the angle between $a$ and $b$.

If $R$ rotates $a$ to the positive $x$-axis, then
$$
\begin{align}
a\cdot b
&=(|a|,0,0)\cdot(b_x,b_y,b_z)\\
&=|a|b_x\\
&=|a||b|\cos(\theta)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

The sum of the square of the length of the cross product and the square of the dot product is
$$
\begin{align}
&|(x,y,z)\times(u,v,w)|^2+((x,y,z)\cdot(u,v,w))^2\\
&=(yw-zv)^2+(zu-xw)^2+(xv-yu)^2+(xu+yv+zw)^2\\
&=(yw)^2+(zv)^2+(zu)^2+(xw)^2+(xv)^2+(yu)^2
+(xu)^2+(yv)^2+(zw)^2\\
&=x^2(u^2+v^2+w^2)+y^2(u^2+v^2+w^2)+z^2(u^2+v^2+w^2)\\
&=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(u^2+v^2+w^2)\\
&=|(x,y,z)|^2|(u,v,w)|^2\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ yield
$$
\begin{align}
|(x,y,z)\times(u,v,w)|^2
&=|(x,y,z)|^2|(u,v,w)|^2-((x,y,z)\cdot(u,v,w))^2\\
&=|(x,y,z)|^2|(u,v,w)|^2-|(x,y,z)|^2|(u,v,w)|^2\cos^2(\theta)\\
&=|(x,y,z)|^2|(u,v,w)|^2(1-\cos^2(\theta))\\
&=|(x,y,z)|^2|(u,v,w)|^2\sin^2(\theta)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
|a\times b|=|a||b||\sin(\theta)|\tag{7}
$$

Comment: $ \mid (x,y,z) \mid ^2 \mid (u,v,w) \mid ^2 - \mid (x,y,z) \mid ^2 \mid (u,v,w) \mid^2 $ turns into just one after subtractions..on part 6 im not understanding how you factored and got the result

Comment: @user3633432: use $1-\cos^2(\theta)=\sin^2(\theta)$

Comment: But the part in part six, how did you factor $ \mid (x,y,z) \mid ^2 \mid (u,v,w) \mid ^2 - \mid (x,y,z) \mid ^2 \mid (u,v,w) \mid ^2 $ into just $ \mid (x,y,z) \mid ^2 \mid (u,v,w) \mid ^2 $.. Because I see a subtraction and that would make it 0 right?

Comment: Maybe you simply just don't want that and you factor it out and make it a one, right?

Comment: NM, I understand part six from |A X B|² = (|A||B|sinθ)² = |A|²|B|²sin²θ = |A|²|b|²(1 - cos²θ) = |A|²|B|² - |A|²|B|²cos²θ = |A|²|B|² - (|A||B|cosθ)² = |A|²|B|² - (A*B)²

Comment: @user3633432: I have added a couple of lines to $(6)$ to improve clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the cross product is the positive area of the parallelogram having $a$ and $b$ as sides:

[image]

From here, it is easy to see that when the angle is 0 or 180 degrees, the area of the parallelogram would be 0. Similarly, the area is largest when the angle is 90 degrees.